# chzn-select unwanted dropdown created jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I have a dropdown styled [with chosen jquery](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), it looks and works good.

This dropdown has two options: Defender and Protector.

When user choses one option it appears a second dropdown (this is strangely not chosen styled) and the ask if defender or protector has or not an ID.

[image]

I do not know how to apply chosen style to generated dropdown.
I have tried appending chzn class on jquery function but has no success.

How to style generated dropdown with chosen style ?

This is the script:

```
$(function () {
    $('#select_guy').change(function () {
        $('#already_exists').show();
        $('.people_class').hide();
        if ($('#select_guy').val() == 'Defender') {
            $("#already_exists").html('');
            $("<option/>").val('0').text('Select option').appendTo("#already_exists");
            $("<option/>").val('Defender-hasID').text('Defender has ID').appendTo("#already_exists");
            $("<option/>").val('Defender-noID').text('Defender has NO ID').appendTo("#already_exists");
        }
        if ($('#select_guy').val() == 'Protector') {
            $("#already_exists").html('');
            $("<option/>").val('0').text('Select otcion').appendTo("#already_exists");
            $("<option/>").val('protector-hasID').text('Protector has ID').appendTo("#already_exists");
            $("<option/>").val('protector-noID').text('Protector has NO ID').appendTo("#already_exists");
        }
    });
    $('#already_exists').change(function () {
        $('.people_class input').val('');
        $("#id_cedente").val('').trigger("liszt:updated");
        $("#id_protector").val('').trigger("liszt:updated");
        $('.people_class').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
        /*if (  $('#already_exists').val() == 'Defender-noID'  )
            $(".chzn-select").val('').trigger("liszt:updated");*/
    });
});
$(".chzn-select").chosen();
$(".chzn-select-deselect").chosen({
    allow_single_deselect: true
});
$(".chzn-select").chosen({
    no_results_text: "No results"
});
```

Please take a look at the  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kktp8/)

## ---update

@Serhiy almost solved it adding
`$('#already_exists').chosen();`
at the end of function as

## [shown here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kktp8/11/)

however a new issue spawned
if user selects an option is ok, but if user suddenly changes his mind and decide to select other option at the first level **{Defender, Protector}** jquery creates a new dropdown so now there are 3!
like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to execute the render method in the main change function.

```
$(".chzn-select").chosen();
```

As the drop-down is being added dynamically and is not being originally rendered.

Also have you looked into select 2 if this is a new project, it may be more developed at this point, esp since you're working with jquery. http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Comment: didn´t know about  select 2, thanks you, I will take a look, however I would like to get this done with chzn first. Could you please post the jsfiddle, where should I add `$(".chzn-select").chosen();` so it is applied to generated dropdown?

Comment: @cMinor I was referring to the 1st change function, $('#select_guy').change(function () {  though yeah if you want to put together a js fiddle for me with this problem I'll try and fix it for you in there

Comment: I added line of code but guess I didn´t do it correctly, could you please  help me with this one? here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Kktp8/6/

Comment: ohh, oops didn't see you had the fiddle up there already, anyways, that rendering call should have been at the bottom of that function after the options were added. Also that 2nd select doesn't have the necessary css class, but the bad part is that had you done those it still didn't work for me. Even if you had rendered the control originally and tried to use $("#already_exists").trigger("liszt:updated"); things still failed. Idk if this is a chosen issues or what but I just I added the rendering at the bottom of method based on ID. http://jsfiddle.net/Kktp8/10/

Comment: ohh in which case the original chosen call you had added isn't necessary. update: http://jsfiddle.net/Kktp8/11/

Comment: There is one issue, hope you can help me, when you select lets say one option, and then change your mind and select other, a new dropdown appears...

Comment: @cMinor actually it's the original one. It's shown then immediately hidden on render, since it doesn't need to render twice it doesn't rehide on 2nd time. Also since the original render / list update didn't work things are gonna get messy / hacky. Please consider the maintainability of this kind of stuff, esp if this is a new thing others will work on. The simple hack is in the fiddle, it aint pretty though http://jsfiddle.net/Kktp8/19/

Comment: could you please add the new fiddle, I guess I modified it the same time you did it..., so  jsfiddle.net/Kktp8/11 is not good, or maybe could you please  post the code you modified?

Comment: Maybe an if statement when is second time (I know this is not good programming but I would like to get rid of this issue) to hide original unstyled dropdown

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did in that 19th fiddle, I had forgotten to hit update.

Comment: Thank you one more time, however, there is an issue, dropdown is hidden but it does not change dependent options... so if I select defender, and change to protector, it shows defender options intead of protector options.

Comment: I think that a hard reset is needed at the second time, so it can change select option

Comment: removed some of the hacks, guess chosen doesn't like rendering things with display:none, nor can it figure out the width on update so I set the width initially. Changed it to update on change so it's getting the new opts. This does make it render initially but that is pretty easy to fix. I am however done working on any of this because it was pretty shitty of you to take away my answer just because you're having more problems with your fancy lookin but flaky library, why I advised Select2 right away. As I feel like I've more than answered the question, goodnight. http://jsfiddle.net/Kktp8/20/

Comment: sorry 'bout that. Thank you